# How to get Panelizer to only affect a specific node

Tags: 7, panels

I have Panelizer installed on my Drupal 7 site. I would like to use Panelizer for only specific nodes and not have it apply on all my nodes (as it currently is). Reading the documentation it seems it is possible to do this but I can't get it to work.

In Admin->Structure->Pages I have the node_view enabled, and I see an entry for my particular node there as well (page-videos_view with the correct url path). If I disable the node_view, then Panelizer is effectively disabled as it doesn't apply any panels even though the view I want is still active.

I assume I am missing a setting somewhere but don't know what it is. Can anyone help out?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out my error. You need to go to Admin->Configuration->Content Authoring->Panelizer and make sure you don't have the Provide Default Panel option selected for the content type you are using Panelizer on.